# How do I create a context sensitive help in Run Configurations?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have to create the help in Run Configurations on my plugin. As the same as this picture.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU5xL.png

I have searched on many sites include Google, or in textbooks, 
but I haven't found how I do it. What should I do ? or Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The help in Run Configurations is only for the different types of launch (Eclipse Application, Java Applet, ....). So are you writing a plugin that adds a new launch type?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing a plugin that adds a new launch type and I would like to create a help for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the normal Eclipse context help system.

You specify the help context id in the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups` extension point using the `helpContextId` of the `launchConfigurationTabGroup`

Example from JUnit:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchConfigurationTabGroups">
  <launchConfigurationTabGroup
        type="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchconfig"
        helpContextId="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.junit_tab_group"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.launcher.JUnitTabGroup"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchConfigurationTabGroup.junit">
     <launchMode
           perspective="org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugPerspective"
           description="%JUnitTabGroupDescription.debug"
           mode="debug">
     </launchMode>
     <launchMode
           description="%JUnitTabGroupDescription.run"
           mode="run">
     </launchMode>
  </launchConfigurationTabGroup>
</extension>
```

Use the `org.eclipse.help.contexts` extension point to declare a file containing the context help ids:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
    <contexts file="contexts_JDT_JUnit.xml" plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.junit"/> 
</extension>
```

and the context file contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.contexts"?>
<contexts>
    <context id="junit_tab_group">
        <description>This launch configuration runs JUnit tests.</description>
        <topic label="Using JUnit" href="gettingStarted/qs-junit.htm"/>
    </context>
</contexts>
```

see the Eclipse help for more details.

Comment: I have tried above, but it seems like that it did not work.

Comment: but, I would love to create a help for my own launch config type for my plugin.

Comment: There are lots of things you can get wrong in this. You need to go through the Eclipse help on the extension points and the help system and check your code.